# Method accepting anything and preserving signature?

Tags: java, reflection

You can define method that will accept anything `(Object... arguments)` but, if you call it with `("A", "B")` and `(["A", "B"])` the value of the `arguments` will be the same `["A", "B"]` - i.e. the original signature will be lost.

Is there any way to preserve it?

P.S. Why I need it:

To remember method and arguments being called and later reply it via reflection. Example when it breaks:

There's an object with method I'd like to call later:

```
MyObj {
  myMeth (String[] array) {...}
}
myObj = new MyObj()
```

I tell computer to call it later with some arguments.

```
callLater(myObj, "myMeth", ["A", "B"])
```

It remembers it, and users reflection to find the actual method and call it.
And it fail, because the original signature got lost, and instead of `(String[])` it tries to find `(String, String)`.

Comment: If I recall correctly, in reflection, variable arguments are treated as arrays always.  So you need to be able to search for `Object[]` as the method parameters

Comment: 'The original signature will be lost' doesn't mean anything. It isn't lost. It is just invoke-able via two different argument lists, which is the whole idea. It isn't clear what your question is actually about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of ambiguity is resolved at the caller side by using casts. In this case, you'd cast the array to `(Object)` first, to have it be treated as a varargs argument. e.g., to pass the array as one argument:

```
callLater(myObj, "myMeth", (Object) new String[] {"A", "B"});
```

To pass two arguments:

```
callLater(myObj, "myMeth", (Object[]) new String[] {"A", "B"});
```

or simply:

```
callLater(myObj, "myMeth", "A", "B");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not very handy, is there any better way? I would like to use it as DSL and keep it simple and nice.

Comment: If you want something "nicer", you're going to have to provide two versions (named differently; can't be overloads) of your method, one that takes varargs and one that takes the array directly.

Comment: Tried, compiler forbids to have two methods `(Object... data)` and `(Object[] data)` with the same name.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "named differently". :-D